# Class group - product of proper ideals

Tags: number-theory, ideal-class-group

I am looking at the definition ([Sutherland](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2017/LectureNotes17.pdf), last page) of class group as the set of proper ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ modulo homothety, where:

- $\mathcal{O}$ is an order in an imaginary quadratic number field $K$
- An ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is proper if and only if $\{\alpha \in K \mid \alpha \mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{a} \} = \mathcal{O}$
- $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are homothetic if and only if there exist $\alpha,\beta \in \mathcal{O}$ such that $\alpha\mathfrak{a} = \beta \mathfrak{b}$.

**It's not clear to me why a product of proper ideals should be proper**. According to Sutherland, it should be "clear". I also think that it's just a matter of some routine letter chasing, but I just can't prove it for some reason it. Is there something I am missing or is it not that trivial?

Comment: If you know also that proper means that the ideal has an inverse (fractional) ideal, then it is clear. From the definition above, perhaps not so.

Comment: I would have preferred to say an ideal of a ring is *proper* if it is a proper subset of the ring. This happens if and only if the ideal does not contain any units of the ring. Now just check that the product of the two ideals contains a unit only if the ideals do.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes I am aware of that, but I was hoping to do it from this definition. Thanks nonetheless, maybe it is indeed clear only when you look at it from the perspective of fractional ideals.

Comment: @RyleeLyman But that is a completely different and non-equivalent definition of proper ideal.